# C++11 cast const iterator pointing to container of shared_ptr objects

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, constants, shared-ptr

I have an STL container whose element type is `const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`.

I want to supply two iterator types to the user:

1. `MyContainer::iterator`

typedefed as `std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>::iterator`
(which should be the same type as `std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>>::const_iterator`

1. `MyContainer::const_iterator`

typedefed as `std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>>::iterator`
(which should be the same type as `std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>>::const_iterator`

In other words, I want the "`const`" to refer to the `MyClass` constness, not `shared_ptr` constness. The solution I found for getting the second iterator type is getting the first one, which is easy (e.g. using `vector::begin`), and then converting it to the second type using `static_cast` (fixme: no need to use `const_cast` because I'm adding constness, not removing it).

Would that be the common good-design way to achieve that, or there's a better/more common way?

Comment: I would use `boost::iterator_facade`.

Comment: Or even better, `boost::iterator_adaptor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> typedefed as `std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>::iterator` (which should be the same type as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>>::const_iterator`

But it probably isn't the same type. Iterators are not just pointers.  If the `iterator` and `const_iterator` types are defined inside `vector` then they are completely unrelated types:

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
    class iterator;
    class const_iterator;
    // ...
```

`vector<const int>` is a different type to `vector<int>` and so their nested types are also different. As far as the compiler is concerned they are completely unrelated types, i.e. you cannot just move `const` around to any point in this type and get compatible types:

```
vector<const shared_ptr<const T>>::iterator
```

You cannot use `const_cast` to convert between unrelated types.  You can use `static_cast` to convert a `vector<T>::iterator` to a `vector<T>::const_iterator` but it's not really a cast, you're constructing the latter from the former, which is allowed because that conversion is required by the standard.

You can convert a `shared_ptr<const T>` to a `shared_ptr<T>` with `const_pointer_cast<T>` but again only because it's defined to work by the standard, not because the types are inherently compatible and not because it "just works" like plain ol' pointers.

Since `vector`'s iterators don't provide the deep-constness you want, you'll need to write your own, but it's not hard:

```
class MyClass { };

class MyContainer
{
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> container_type;

    container_type m_cont;

public:

    typedef container_type::iterator iterator;

    class const_iterator
    {
        typedef container_type::const_iterator internal_iterator;
        typedef std::iterator_traits<internal_iterator> internal_traits;

        const_iterator(internal_iterator i) : m_internal(i) { }
        friend class MyContainer;

    public:

        const_iterator() { }
        const_iterator(iterator i) : m_internal(i) { }

        typedef std::shared_ptr<const MyClass> value_type;
        typedef const value_type& reference;
        typedef const value_type* pointer;
        typedef internal_traits::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef internal_traits::iterator_category iterator_category;

        const_iterator& operator++() { ++m_internal; return *this; }
        const_iterator operator++(int) { const_iterator tmp = *this; ++m_internal; return tmp; }

        reference operator*() const { m_value = *m_internal; return m_value; }
        pointer operator->() const { m_value = *m_internal; return &m_value; }

        // ...

    private:
        internal_iterator m_internal;
        mutable value_type m_value;
    };

    iterator begin() { return m_cont.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(m_cont.begin()); }

    // ...    
};
```

That iterator type is mising a few things (`operator--`, `operator+`) but they're easy to add, following the same ideas as already shown.

The key point to notice is that in order for `const_iterator::operator*` to return a reference, there needs to be a `shared_ptr<const MyClass>` object stored as a member of the iterator. That member acts as a "cache" for the `shared_ptr<const MyClass>` value, because the underlying container's real elements are a different type, `shared_ptr<MyClass>`, so you need somewhere to cache the converted value so a reference to it can be returned.  N.B. Doing this slightly breaks the iterator requirements, because the following doesn't work as expected:

```
MyContainer::const_iterator ci = c.begin();
const shared_ptr<const MyClass>& ref = *ci;
const MyClass* ptr = ref.get();
++ci;
(void) *ci;
assert( ptr == ref.get() );  // FAIL!
```

The reason the assertion fails is that `*ci` doesn't return a reference to an underlying element of the container, but to a member of the iterator, which gets modified by the following increment and dereference.  If this behaviour isn't acceptable you'll need to return a proxy from your iterator instead of caching a value.  Or return a `shared_ptr<const MyClass>` when the `const_iterator` is dereferenced.  (The difficulties of getting this 100% right is one of the reasons STL containers don't try to model deep constness!)

A lot of the effort of defining your own iterator types is done for you by the [`boost::iterator_adaptor`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html)  utility, so the example above is only really useful for exposition.  With that adaptor you'd only need to do this to get your own custom iterator types with the desired behaviour:

```
struct iterator
: boost::iterator_adaptor<iterator, container_type::iterator>
{
    iterator() { }
    iterator(container_type::iterator i) : iterator_adaptor(i) { }
};

struct const_iterator
: boost::iterator_adaptor<const_iterator, container_type::const_iterator, std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>, boost::use_default, std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>>
{
    const_iterator() { }
    const_iterator(iterator i) : iterator_adaptor(i.base()) { }
    const_iterator(container_type::const_iterator i) : iterator_adaptor(i) { }
};
```

Comment: Then what should I do? I think what I need is very expected from a programmer to need, I mean, I want to have an iterator type which protects the pointed object. What do all the other users of containers-of-pointers in the world do?

Comment: Define your own iterator types, instead of just returning `vector::iterator`, and make those types do the conversions from `shared_ptr<MyClass>` to `shared_ptr<const MyClass>` as needed

Comment: How do I define my own iterator types? I don't have access to STL internals (and I don't want to have it either...)

Comment: You don't need access to any internals to write an iterator, just write a type that models the iterator concept, wrapping a `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>`, but returning a `const shared_ptr<const MyClass>&` when the `const_iterator` type is dereferenced

Comment: I've added the start of a custom iterator implementation

Comment: Someone suggested I write a deep_shared_ptr class which wraps shared_ptr and const deep_shared_ptr does deep constness. Maybe this is better than a new iterator class? (I don't want the iterator to contain a copy of the object and I don't want proxy mess...)

Comment: That could be simpler, yes. The `boost::iterator_adaptor` version works without a proxy or embedded shared_ptr member though (as @aschepler also suggests)

Comment: Even worse than the failure you noted is `const std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>& ref = *c.begin();`.  Instant dangling reference.  And hmm, I guess we don't really need to implement `dereference()`, since the public `operator*` and so on will have correct types.

Comment: How does boost::iterator_adaptor work? Why can't I get the same thing with plain C++ code?

Comment: You can, there's no magic.  The `iterator_adaptor` version returns by value, not reference, and takes care of all the boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

`boost::iterator_adaptor` makes it pretty easy to define your own iterator types based on another iterator type.  So you can set it up so that `*iter` is a `const shared_ptr<MyClass>&` or `const shared_ptr<const MyClass>&` as desired.

Though in the `const_iterator` case, dereferencing can't return a `const shared_ptr<const MyClass>&` if what you actually have is `shared_ptr<MyClass>`.  So we'll define `const_iterator::reference` as just `shared_ptr<const MyClass>` and return by value.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>

class MyContainer {
public:

    class iterator;
    class const_iterator;

    class iterator :
        public boost::iterator_adaptor<
            iterator,                         // This class, for CRTP
            std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>::const_iterator,
                                              // Base type
            const std::shared_ptr<MyClass> >  // value_type
    {
    public:
        iterator() {}
        iterator(const iterator&) = default;

    private:
        friend class MyContainer;                 // allow private constructor
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access; // allow dereference()
        explicit iterator(base_type iter) : iterator_adaptor(iter) {}
        const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>& dereference() const
            { return *base_reference(); }
    };

    class const_iterator :
        public boost::iterator_adaptor<
            const_iterator,                        // This class, for CRTP
            std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>::const_iterator,
                                                   // Base type
            const std::shared_ptr<const MyClass>,  // value_type
            boost::use_default,                    // difference_type
            std::shared_ptr<const MyClass> >       // reference_type
    {
    public:
        const_iterator();
        const_iterator(const const_iterator&) = default;

        // Implicit conversion from iterator to const_iterator:
        const_iterator(const iterator& iter) : iterator_adaptor(iter.base()) {}

    private:
        friend class MyContainer;                 // allow private constructor
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access; // allow dereference()
        explicit const_iterator(base_type iter) : iterator_adaptor(iter) {}
        std::shared_ptr<const MyClass> dereference() const
            { return *base_reference(); }
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(mVec.begin()); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(mVec.end()); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return cend(); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(mVec.begin()); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return const_iterator(mVec.end()); }

private:
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> mVec;
};
```

Comment: If what I actually have is const shared_ptr<MyClass>, can the iterator_adaptor make operator* return a reference to const shared_ptr<const MyClass>? fixme: shared_ptr doesn't allow this conversion (instead, it tries to construct a new shared_ptr)

Comment: `iterator_adaptor::operator*` will return whatever you specify as the reference type.  The constructor `shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<U>&)` (here with `T = const U`) will do the Right Thing, and the constructed pointer will share ownership with the original.

Comment: I understand, but why is it allowed to return any type? Why can't I do the type cast by myself, but the boost library just bypasses the limitation so easily? I just want to have a reference const shared_ptr<const T>& point to an object const shared_ptr<T>...

Comment: You can't get a `const shared_ptr<const T>&` from a `const shared_ptr<T>` because a `shared_ptr<T>` is not a `shared_ptr<const T>`.  If didn't specify a `reference_type` and allowed boost to use the default `const shared_ptr<const MyClass>&`, it would have a compile error just as much.  The version which makes `operator*` return by value works because the `return` statement implicitly constructs a copy `shared_ptr<const T>`.

Comment: Then operator*() has to return b value. It means I don't have access to the original shared pointer anyway. But since it's const, in my case, this limitation doesn't really matter. The problem is that operator* returns be value, but I can solve that by using boost::indirect_iterator (i.e. iterators point to shared objects) and get shared pointers using std::enable_shared_from_this, when I really need them. Problem solved...

Answer (score 1):

shared_ptr and other standard smart pointers are not designed with deep-constness in mind. They are trying to be as close to raw pointer usage as possible, and raw pointer's const-ness does not affect the pointee's const-ness.

Andrei Alexandrescu's [Loki::SmartPtr](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00529.html) (described in his *Modern C++ Design*) implements reference counting and deep const-ness as policies, which would give you the effect you're looking for. If you don't mind switching to a non-standard smart pointer in order to get non-standard behavior, that may be one way to go.

Comment: it's not non-standard behavior, what I'm looking for is very expected from a container of pointers

Comment: No, it's not, it can only work if `vector<T>::iterator` is just a typedef for `T*` but that's not guaranteed

Comment: It's non-standard in the sense that the C++ standard library's pointers don't support what you want out of the box.

Comment: Some people want it, some people don't. If you want a drop-in replacement for raw pointers, you probably don't because it'll break your (const-correct) code. You could write your own deep_shared_ptr, which wraps up a shared_ptr but supplies const-correct accessors.